# How to change this C++ (OpenCV) code so it takes an image instead of a video?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, face-recognition, face-detection

I am new to C++ and trying to convert this code so it can take an image instead of a video.
This is for face detection with OpenCV. I can figure out that to Mat, I need to pass an image instead of video, just not sure how exactly to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
int main()
{
VideoCapture capture;
//open capture object at location zero (default location for webcam)

capture.open(0);

//set height and width of capture frame
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);

Mat cameraFeed;

SkinDetector mySkinDetector;

Mat skinMat;

//start an infinite loop where webcam feed is copied to cameraFeed matrix
//all of our operations will be performed within this loop
while(1){

//store image to matrix
capture.read(cameraFeed);

//show the current image
imshow("Original Image",cameraFeed);

skinMat= mySkinDetector.getSkin(cameraFeed);

imshow("Skin Image",skinMat);

waitKey(30);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'pass an image'.
If you're not reading from a video source and want to read from a file on disk then remove the following code:

```
VideoCapture capture;
//open capture object at location zero (default location for webcam)

capture.open(0);

//set height and width of capture frame
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
```

And change Mat cameraFeed to:

```
Mat cameraFeed = imread("/path/to/image.jpg");
```

Or you could just create a function and pass your image to that.

```
void detectSkin(Mat img)
{
    SkinDetector mySkinDetector;
    Mat skinMat;

    //show the current image
    imshow("Original Image",img);

    skinMat= mySkinDetector.getSkin(img);

    imshow("Skin Image",skinMat);

    // Changed to 3000 milliseconds so you'll have time to see it.
    waitKey(3000);
}

int main()
{
    Mat img = imread("myimage.jpg");
    detectSkin(img);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the whole code. In this code, you are using continuous images from video using a while loop. Use the single image as

```
Mat cameraFeed = imread("/path/to/image.jpg");
imshow("Original Image",cameraFeed);

Mat skinMat= mySkinDetector.getSkin(cameraFeed);
imshow("Skin Image",skinMat);

waitKey(30);
```